# /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

I am getting following exception when apps lunch but not crash.Device Kernel version 3.0.13

Why am I  getting this exception?  I searched with exception in google.But I could not find any answer. 
LOG::

```
09-15 17:23:03.504: E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(236): Object tried to add another INFO callback
09-15 17:23:03.543: E/AudioYusuHardware(103): setParameters still have param.size() = 1
09-15 17:23:03.556: E/WifiStateMachine(236): set suspend optimizations failed!
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236): mtprof entry can not found!
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:852)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:653)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:225)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7054)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:756)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:432)
09-15 17:23:07.368: E/ActivityManager(236):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Mind to post any relevant code? What are you doing in that particular app/activity?

Comment: IN ACTIVITY I have not open any file or folder.

Comment: Exception have been seen in apps main activity

Comment: This is not an exception from the poster's app at all, but rather from a system level process.  Unless the poster is using a custom ROM, it's just buggy code that shipped on the device and there's not much that can be done about it.  It might be triggered by something an app has done, but that's not clear from the posted information.  What was going on when this occurred?

Comment: When Apps lunch or start up of main activity, it shows exception in logcat from real device  but not crash.